Is it possible to raise an exception on FutureWarning (pandas)?
I am seeing a FutureWarning in the output of my code, coming from the pandas library.
I would like to catch when this is occurring in the code execution. The natural way would be to request pandas to raise an exception rather than printing a warning message.
Is there way to do this? If an exception cannot be raised is there some other way of catching this condition during runtime?

Why would you want an exception?  That would render your code useless.  The FutureWarning doesn't affect functionality in any way.

Because I want to fix it. I believe the particular warning I'm getting is leading to an unrecoverable error downstream (later in the code).

Use Python's built-in warnings module:
# Convert FutureWarning to an exception
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=FutureWarning)

